# How to make tensorflow.keras.model.predict() output a generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I know, `tensorflow.keras.model.predict()`  can receive a `generator` or a `numpy array`, but the output of this function is always a `numpy array`. Sometimes the output `array` will be too big so that `OOM Memory Errors` occur.

Is there any suggestion to output a generator when I call `tensorflow.keras.model.predict()` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a generator wrapper:

```py
def generator_predict(data_gen):
    for data in data_gen:
        yield tensorflow.keras.model.predict(data)
```

Then when you use it:

```py
predict_gen = generator_predict(data_gen)

predicted_output = next(predict_gen)
...
```

Something like that should work just fine.